# Деплой проекта Django на боевой Linux-сервер

Tags: django, развертывание

По видимому, организовать репозиторий проекта с рабочей версией кода на боевом сервере - дело несложное, однако возникают некоторые затруднения в следующих моментах:

1. Сервер Linux настроен, и тестовые Django-проекты разных версий крутятся на нём соответствующим образом, когда создаются непосредственно на этом сервере командами самого Django в своих виртуальных средах.
2. Для нового проекта также создается своя виртуальная среда и рабочий Django-каталог, настраиваются привязки к WSGI и веб-серверу, тестируется на предмет доступа к сайту из любого места с получением стартовой страницы пустого проекта.
3. Затем, клонируется репозиторий с рабочим кодом на сервер из Github командой  `git clone`. После этого рабочий код из клонированной папки репозитория перебрасывается простым копированием в протестированный пустой проект и всё это выдает ошибку "Internal Server Error".
4. Имена и иерархия папок пустого и рабочего проекта  полностью соответствуют.
5. Пробовал запускать из клонированной папки с настройками на неё и привязками ссылок - та же ошибка. Перепривязываю настройки на пустой проект - всё в порядке, работает.

Сам проект разрабатывается на Visual Studio 2017 с использованием расширения Git, а исходный код хранится в Github.

Сильно подозреваю, что такой метод вызовет смех у профи, но после прочтения нескольких мануалов, правильное понимание этой технологии так и не сложилось, кроме того, что для безопасности исходников рекомендуется использовать голые - bare репозитории.

Вот, в направлении такой bare-технологи и хотелось бы получить конкретные рекомендации и, конечно, указание на возможные ошибки по приведенному выше моему "методу" деплоя! Как в данном случае запустить Django-проект с использованием bare и Github репозитория на сервере Linux?

Comment: Очевидно, надо читать логи и выяснять, откуда взялся Internal Server Error. А деплоить через команду git неправильно

Comment: Наполовину решил задачу. Оказалось, не везде исправил имена проекта при переименовании вручную. В данном случае поправил имя в файле wsgi.py проекта. Отсутствие привязки обнаружилось в логах wsgi-службы.

Comment: Проект запустился, но запустился с начальной версией исходников. Теперь каким-то образом необходимо переместиться в последнюю master версию кода..